# Changing Button's BackgroundImage in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, background-image, dispatcher

In my c# app I am trying to change a button's background image and change it back after a few seconds. However, the background image is not changed until after the timer is up and then is instantly changed back to its original image before you can see the change.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myImage.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.newImage;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    myImage.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.myImage;
}
```

Comment: Your code is most likely blocking the main thread. Is this winforms or wpf?

Comment: That's because rendering is done on the GUI thread and the code halts the GUI Thread by a sleep statement.  Use a timer and event instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a WPF app, add the `DispatcherTimer` as shown in the following code snippet:

```
DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.Click += button1_Click;
    _dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
    _dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myImage.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.newImage;
    _dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    myImage.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.myImage;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad it works for you. Good luck with your project. Best regards,